# Override maxlength input using Django form {{ form.as_p }}

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

In Django when I create a form from a model, in the template I use `{{ form.as_p }}` and for text inputs it creates the follow code:

```
<input id="id_var1" maxlength="8" name="var1" type="text">
```

Is it possible to override the `maxlength` value (in this case "8") with a variable I have in the `views.py`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your form fields, you can override the widget and add `attrs` parameter for custom HTML attributes.

```
class MyCustomForm(forms.ModelForm):

    var1 = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
            # override/add custom HTML attributes in this dictionary
            'maxlength': '20',
        })
    )

    class Meta:
        model = MyCustomModel
        fields = ['var1', ...]
```

You can update the `maxlength` from a view like this:

```
form = MyCustomForm()
form.fields['var1'].widget.attrs['maxlength'] = '20'
```

Comment: If I use your code is working, but the new length is a variable "new_length=20" within the views.py . How can I pass that to the form? Thanks

Comment: Alex's answer is a bit more simple and straightforward. You should see if his solution works for you.

Comment: Your last update to the answer is working fine: `form.fields['var1'].widget.attrs['maxlength'] = '20'`. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML `maxlength` parameter is handled by the browser, not by the Django's views. You should tweak your form or template to change the length of the field:

```
class YourForm(forms.Form):
    var_1 = forms.CharField(max_length=8)


def your_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    max_length = int(request.GET['max_length'])
    form = YourForm(request.POST or None)
    form.fields['var_1'].max_length = max_length
    return render(request, 'template.html', dict(form=form))
```

Comment: I have tried to add to my view: `form.fields['var_1'].max_length = new_length`. I receive no error message, but it is not working, the max_length is still 8. My form is coming from a template `class YourForm(forms.ModelForm):`